# Invalide credentials JWT Symfony 6

Tags: symfony, hash, jwt

Having searched long and hard to understand my problem, I could see that the subject had been discussed a lot. But none of the solutions I came across helped me to understand and solve my problem.

I installed JWT on a Symfony 6 REST api I'm developing. I set up the user creation. I now want to be able to generate a JWT token with my user. But the endpoint returns :

> {     "code": 401,    "message": "Invalid credentials." }

And since then, I don't understand what is wrong with it. I went to see where it was going in the vendors hoping to understand, but I stop at the first `dispatch()` in the `executeAuthenticator()` method of the `AuthenticatorManager` class.

My sources are :

```
    security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Personnage\Domain\Entity\User:
            algorithm: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                username_path: login
                #password_path: password
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~


            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/create-account, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

```
    path: /connexion
    methods: ['POST']
```

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 3600
    user_identity_field: login
```

I also put the creation of my user, in case the problem comes from there. I don't use Symfony User (no doctrine mapping and other services, I don't use the "magic" of the framework, which can sometimes impact details). It impacted me for the generation of the hashed password. And I wonder if it is not the hash of my password that is the problem.

```
[...]
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\InMemoryUser;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;

final class CreateAccount
{
    public function __construct(
        private UserRepository $repository,
        private UserPasswordHasherInterface $hasher
    ) {}

    public function __invoke(string $login, string $mail, string $password, string $genre): User
    {
        $hash = $this->hasher->hashPassword(
            (new InMemoryUser($login, $password)),
            $password
        );

        $user = new User(
            Uuid::v4(),
            $login,
            $mail,
            $hash,
            $genre,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            Uuid::v4(), //Todo : replace with real Uuid of city
            null,
            0,
            2,
            5,
            new \DateTimeImmutable(),
            new \DateTimeImmutable()
        );

        ($this->repository)->create($user);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Personnage\Domain\Entity;

use DateTimeImmutable;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;

class User
{
    public function __construct(
        private Uuid $uuid,
        private string $login,
        private string $mail,
        private string $password,
        private string $genre,
        private int $level,
        private int $intellect,
        private int $strength,
        private int $charisma,
        private Uuid $city,
        private ?Uuid $profession,
        private float $money,
        private int $hunger,
        private int $shape,
        private DateTimeImmutable $created,
        private DateTimeImmutable $lastConnexion
    ) {}

    public function getUuid(): Uuid
    {
        return $this->uuid;
    }

    public function getLogin(): string
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    public function getMail(): string
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getGenre(): string
    {
        return $this->genre;
    }

    public function getLevel(): int
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

    public function getIntellect(): int
    {
        return $this->intellect;
    }

    public function getStrength(): int
    {
        return $this->strength;
    }

    public function getCharisma(): int
    {
        return $this->charisma;
    }

    public function getCity(): Uuid
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function getProfession(): ?Uuid
    {
        return $this->profession;
    }

    public function getMoney(): float
    {
        return $this->money;
    }

    public function getHunger(): int
    {
        return $this->hunger;
    }

    public function getShape(): int
    {
        return $this->shape;
    }

    public function getCreated(): DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function getLastConnexion(): DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->lastConnexion;
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me to understand :)

Comment: After checking JWT, I think there is a problem with the password hash. But I don't see the problem either, I'm using the right service for that.

Answer (score 0):

The particularity of my development is that I do not use the Doctrine ORM. I only use it for database connection and queries via DBal directly.

My problem is solved with the creation of a custom provider by following this documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider

And adding to my User entity the interfaces :

- Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface
- Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface